# "He has a problem on/in his ears."

Tags: prepositions

> He has a problem ON his ears.

> He has a problem IN his ears.

What's the difference in meaning between the two sentences above?

Comment: Generally not on. "on the outside of his ears".

Comment: I would assume _on_ to mean an injury to the external ear, and _in_ a problem with the internal part.

Answer (score 1):

Both prepositions are a little strange with "problem." A common construction is "a problem **with**." "In" and "on" are very positional prepositions, and a "problem" is more of an idea (there's a *difficulty* with his ears). I could imagine using "in" when discussing the exact placement of the problem ("There's a problem somewhere in my inner ear"), but "on" is so specific as to suggest that the problem is a physical object.